# To insert into MongoDB: Does the size of document converted to BSON change?

Tags: mongodb, bson

Ok I am new to MongoDB and been reading a book about it, some where it is saying

> "Documents larger than 4MB (when converted to BSON ) cannot be saved
>   to database "

Ok...4MB cap for documents? The thing that confused me is the thing they say in parenthesis : *( when converted to BSON )* : So the size is getting changed when converted to BSON?

because a few line later it is saying:

> "To give you an idea of how much 4MB is, the entire text of ***War and
>   Peace*** is just 3.14 MB "

What? Ok now I am confused.  Help Me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory, the BSON file also contains the field names which take up space and some overhead. In general, the overhead is not more than a few bytes. Besides some document overhead (a few bytes), each value stored also has some additional storage bytes. For a simple string it's 6 bytes extra (1 for the type, 4 for the length and 1 for a trailing \0 character). You can see the overhead on the [bsonspec.org](http://bsonspec.org/#/specification) website. The length of a simple string itself doesn't change "when converted to BSON", but the addition of the length etc makes it a tiny bit larger. Most of the drivers have a helper function to figure out how large a document would be. In PHP you would do:

```
<?php
$document = array(
    '_id' => new MongoId(),
    'name' => 'Derick'
);
echo strlen(bson_encode($document)), "\n";
?>
```

Which in this case prints `39`.

Also, the current document limit is 16 MB- it has changed since the book was written.

Comment: very interesting. Thanks Sir. So a question: Let's say I have a file of text, comma separated, etc..which on my local machine this text file takes 5 Mega Bytes ... so this 5 Mega Bytes IS NOT something I can compare against that 16 MB cap and say oh well this is 5MB and that is 16MB, so it will be fine ... Did I get it right?

Comment: Pretty much, but it won't be that much off. It all depends on how many files and fieldname lengths etc. You would also generally not store a whole CSV file in *one* document. You can compare a document with a row in a normal database mostly.

Comment: Hmmm...So it was a VERY BAD design I had in mind?  Each patient had a  PatientID, I wanted to save those as Key and then for Values of those patient, each one had a big text file that on local disk was taking somewhere between 2 to 45 Mega Bytes...I was thinking of saving the whole text file for each patient like a BLOB...

Comment: I wouldn't do that as you wouldn't be able to query on that if you store them in one field... if you don't care about that, have a look at GridFS which is for *file* storage.